# ASP.NET VB.NET Add Indent to Programmatically created file

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, streamwriter

After searching Google, and finding only answers to *XML indent*, *"just use Visual Studio's auto indent"* and *"that would be crazy to write your own auto-indenter"* I've decided to come to the good place: **StackOverflow...**

**Question:**
***1. How do I add an 'indent' to a programmatically created file?***
- I would be generating the files via the System.IO class / streamwriter, unless someone can tell me of a better way, I just want to generate a file from my asp.net page, a windows app or possible a batch file (well, maybe not this last one)... to generate a class file, such as *Employee.vb* OR *EmployeeDAL.vb*

**Why:**
I've decided that I'm a bit bored of writing the same BOL and DAL code for every database table I write, and at the moment I'm stuck with ASP.NET due to work constraints, otherwise I would just move over to something like Ruby on Rails or some PHP framework, but this isn't an option, so please don't suggest this.

**So...**
I know how to get the names of all my table columns, their data types, their lengths,... yadda yaddda..., and I haven't actually fleshed out a working file, but from experience / knowledge, and a bit of googling I think the main bits will be 'fairly easy'.

However all I really want to know, is how to I add an indentation when I create my file?

Over thinking it:
Perhaps, I'm over thinking it, and when I sit down to write it, I'll realise, I just need to add some spaces to my string...

```
"    private _" & db_field_name & " as " variable_type(db_type)
```

- Any help appreciated...
- Cheers.

Ps...
We're using .NET 2.0 - I know, I know, there are so many reasons we should be using Ruby, PHP, or .NET 4.0 (hopefully this is coming this year - to our team) - but there is nothing I can do about it at the moment, and we use .NET.

Comment: Would it just be sw.Write("\t"); 
- Could it really be this easy??

Comment: Yeah I know, sorry by this, I meant, we should be getting it this year.

Comment: IMO, PHP would be stepping backwards compared .NET 2.0 (even .NET 1.1 depending on the version of PHP). Ruby would be more of a step sideways. .NET 2.0 is so powerful that 3.0 and 3.5 were literally built on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you're not using [T4 templates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) to do this?

Also, there isn't any magic available to indent files created by code generation; you're responsible to do that.  Of course, if you use T4 to generate your code, most likely you won't have to worry about this (the nature of T4 means this question is almost always moot).

Comment: T4 looks good, work is only on Visual Studio 2005 at the moment, and T4 is 2008 upwards.  But we started testing / moving our integration engine over Visual Studio 2010 today, so hopefully we'll be running with that very soon.  I personally have VS 2010 already though, so I think I'll check that out.  

I knew StackOverflow was the place to come. +1

Comment: Or at least I would try it out at home, but I only have express edition :(

Comment: @Duncan I thought T4 was available in VS 2005 as well, though I could be wrong.  It might not be available within the Express editions.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: "the nature of T4 means this question is almost always moot" - I'm happy with that. :)

Comment: & @Dr Wily's Apprentice are you able to help out this is issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571444/asp-net-vb-net-remote-login-portal-setup

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [the IndentedTextWriter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.indentedtextwriter.aspx) has support for indentation that you may find useful.

You may want to look at the System.CodeDom namespace in general, as it may be applicable to what you're trying to do.